# How to add value to combobox from column?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I want to set some data to combobox. This code block doesn't work in `Sub Auto_Open()`. How to solve this problem? What can I do?

```
With Sheet2.ComboBoxTetiklenenEvent
.Clear
.ListFillRange = "Sheet2!B10:B16"
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the items during the `DropButtonClick` event, which fires when the users clicks the drop down button.

For example:

```
Private Sub ComboBox21_DropButtonClick()
    Me.ComboBox21.ListFillRange = "Sheet2!B10:B16"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `.Clear` method it should work. The reason it is erroring is the `.Clear` is used to clear manually added items. Therefore, changing the `.ListFillRange` will be sufficient.

However you could use this if you really want to use the `.Clear` method:

`With Sheet2.ComboBoxTetiklenenEvent
    .Clear
    For Each r In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B10:B16")
        .AddItem r.Value
    Next r
End With`

Comment: I write this but I get error fourth line.                                                      `Private Sub ComboBoxTetiklenenEvent_DropButtonClick()
With Sheet2.ComboBoxTetiklenenEvent
    .Clear
    For Each r In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B10:B16")
        .AddItem r.Value
    Next r
End With
End Sub`  Fourth line is: `For Each r In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B10:B16")`

Comment: What is the name of sheet 2 alternatively use `Sheet2.Range("B10:B16")`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @joelc and @user3561813..

I solved my problem. I renamed my 'sheet2' to 'components'. I used 'sheet2' in macro everytime. I changed it and solved that.